# Problem with getting user input , How do i solve this problem?

Tags: dart

```
    import 'dart:io';
void main (List<String> args){

  print('Enter name');
 String? name = stdin.readLineSync();
print (name);

print ("Enter first digit");
 int?num1 = int.parse(stdin.readLinesync()!);

print ("Enter second digit");
 int num2? = int. parse(stdin.readLineSync()!);

int result = num1 + num2;
print(result);

}
```

There is absolutely nothing wrong with the code. I'm sure of it.

Getting user input in the debug console in visual studio code is a bit cumbersome. I'm input a integer alright. But when I want to print. It doesn't work quite accurately.
f
For instance when input an integer in the console and i want to print "the number you entered is(the integer that was imputed in the console), on the integer  displays but the string doesn't display.

I'm also finding it difficult perform any arithmetic calculations with the integers that i input in the debug console.

Also when I specify that the user input should be an integer, I'm able to input an integer and a string as well. This shouldn't be

Comment: Show code.  We're not that psychic. :)

Comment: Are you running this in the normal terminal window, or inside the integrated terminal in VSC?  If so, you may need to fiddle with the "Dart: CLI Console" setting in VSC.

Comment: I'm not running dart using the terminal..i simply click on the run button in vscode and it complies and display the output in the debug console